# Python Function not running?

Tags: python

It's my first time here and I'm kinda panicking. I have an assignment to code Rock, Paper, Scissors in Python. (I use Python 3.1) and for some reason the function is not running...?

Here's the code:

```
hscore = 0
cscore = 0
tries = 0

#computer choice
rock = ("rock")
paper = ("paper")
scissors = ("scissors")
rps = (rock, paper, scissors)
cchoice = random.choice(rps)
choice = input("\nWhat do you choose? <rock, paper, scissors>: ")
tries +=1

def humanfunction():
    if choice == "rock":
        if cchoice == scissors:
            print("Human wins this round.")
            hscore +=1
    if choice == "scissors":
        if cchoice == paper:
            print("Human wins this round.")
            hscore +=1
    if choice == "paper":
        if cchoice == rock:
            print("Human wins this round.")
            hscore +=1
    if cchoice == choice:
        print("Tie.")
def compfunction():
    if cchoice == scissors:
        if choice == "paper":
            print("Computer wins this round.")
            cscore +=1
    if cchoice == rock:
        if choice == "scissors":
            print("Computer wins this round.")
            cscore +=1
    if cchoice == paper:
        if choice == "rock":
            print("Computer wins this rounud.")
            cscore +=1
    if cchoice == choice:
        print("Tie.")

def choose():
    tries = 0
    while 0 == 0:
        choice = input("\nWhat do you choose? <rock, paper, scissors>: ")
        tries +=1
        print("\nHuman choice: ", choice)
        print("Computer choice: ", cchoice)
        print("Finished game number", tries)
        if tries == 10:
            print("Limit reached!")
            break
humanfunction()
compfunction()
choose()
```

I've been trying to solve this for days now and for some reason, when I run the code, it doesn't show up who won. Help would be appreciated <3

EDIT:
here's what i get when i run the code:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTNtR.png)

the program is actually supposed to show this: 
[output2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ng6Rx.png)

Comment: Could you post your error message or your output from this program?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/truth.html  - read it, remember it. Several _*things*_ in python are considered `False` - like any kind of `empty set`, `list`, `dict` or ...... `0`

Comment: Many things: 1) You call the `human`/`comp` functions once, rather than in your loop. 2) `choice` in the `choose()` function will refer to a local variable and not overwrite the global...  Start with a program that has simpler logic (e.g. guess a number), get that flow working, then move the RPS logic back.

Comment: If your program does not what you expect, there are generally 2 options: 1. use a debugger and go through it line by line. 2. cut it down until you understand what it does.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my take on your code. 

The main reason it wasn't running is that your  `cscore` variable was being referenced before it was initialized, because you had setup `cscore` as a `global` variable, but didn't declare it as a `global` variable in your function.

You also needed to import the `random` library

Also instead of doing 4 `if/then` statements I combined them into 1 `if/then` statement

EDIT: cleaned up the code a little more

EDIT 2: no more globals, avoid globals if possible

```
import random    


def get_human_choice():
    valid_choice = False
    while not valid_choice:
        choice = input("\nWhat do you choose? <rock, paper, scissors>: ")
        if choice == 'rock' or 'paper' or 'scissors':
            valid_choice = True

    return choice   


def get_comp_choice():
    rps = ('rock', 'paper', 'scissors')
    comp_choice = random.choice(rps)
    return comp_choice    


def human_winner(comp_choice):
    print("The computer chooses: %s" % comp_choice)
    print("Human wins this round.")    


def comp_winner(comp_choice):
    print("The computer chooses: %s" % comp_choice)
    print("Computer wins this round.")    


def stats(attempts, human_score, comp_scored, tie_score):
    print("Finished game number: %s" % attempts)
    print('Human Score: %s' % human_score)
    print('Computer Score: %s' % comp_scored)
    print('Ties: %s' % tie_score)    


def play_game(human_score, comp_score, tie_score):
    choice = get_human_choice()
    comp_choice = get_comp_choice()    

    if choice == 'rock':
        if comp_choice == 'scissors':
            human_winner(comp_choice)
            human_score += 1
        else:
            comp_winner(comp_choice)
            comp_score += 1
    elif choice == 'scissors':
        if comp_choice == 'paper':
            human_winner(comp_choice)
            human_score += 1
        else:
            comp_winner(comp_choice)
            comp_score += 1
    elif choice == 'paper':
        if comp_choice == 'rock':
            human_winner(comp_choice)
            human_score += 1
        else:
            comp_winner(comp_choice)
            comp_score += 1
    elif choice == comp_choice:
        print("Tie.")
        tie_score += 1    

    return human_score, comp_score, tie_score    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tries = 1
    h_score, c_score, t_score = 0, 0, 0
    while tries <= 10:
        h_score, c_score, t_score = play_game(h_score, c_score, t_score)    

        if tries == 10:
            print("\nLimit reached!\n")
            stats(tries, h_score, c_score, t_score)
            break
        else:
            tries += 1
```

Comment: This doesn't really work as intended since you are only letting the computer make a choice once, plus encouraging a beginner to make excessive usage of globals is promoting bad habits, ultimately doing more harm than good.

Comment: heck thank you! unfortunately this is an assignment for school and we haven't gone over the making something global thing  yet ^^;;; (its frustrating lol) is there any other way? if not, thank you for your code nonetheless!

Comment: Updated without globals, and the computers choice changes every round.